# String Manipulation issues when extracting information from strings

Tags: c#, string, information-extraction

I am running into an issue when manipulating strings when cleaning up a text file before converting it into a CSV. 
my file looks like this..

> ```
> ^Smith, Joe
>  ACME Inc.
>  66 Main St, #1517
>  Ottawa, ON
>  Ottawa ON  K1A 0P4
>  Phone: (613) 123-4567
> ^Jefferson, Bubba
>  Farmers Federation
>  Farmer Unit
>  50 Otherway Drive
>  North Bay ON  P1B 0A4
>  Phone: (705) 123-4567
>  Fax: (705) 234-5678
> ^McStabber, Stabby
>  66 backwards St
>  Unit #412
>  Ottawa ON  K1A 0P4
>  Phone: (613) 123-4567
> ^Weaver, Basket
>  Old and New
>  470 bamboo St E, Unit 63
>  Belleville ON  K8N 1G1
>  Phone: (613) 123-4567 Ext. 890
> ^Smith, Joe
>  ACME Inc.
>  66 Main St, #1517
>  Ottawa, ON
>  Ottawa ON  K1A 0P4
>  Phone: (613) 123-4567
> ```

When You look at Stabby McStabber, it is laid out properly. Bubba and Basket are examples of the problem I am having.

Basket for some reason when I encounter a record like that the address will populate in the city, this causes me issues when I convert the CSV to a datatable because of the shift of the cells. 
The Bubba record type issue I can figure out what to do.

I know it has to do with how I am extracting the information, just don't know how to fix it when I run into those lines.

Here is the code that I wrote to take this text file and write it to a CSV.

```
public class PIADATA
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string Suite { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Alternate { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PIADATA pia = new PIADATA();
        string strFileContent;

        List<string> NewData = new List<string>();

        List<string> lstFinishedData = new List<string>();

        string[] myDataString;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        #region Read File to a List

        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(@"C:\TestData2.txt"))
        {
            while ((strFileContent = rd.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (strFileContent.Contains("Details  &raquo;"))
                {
                    int nStartOf = strFileContent.IndexOf("Details");
                    int nEndOf = strFileContent.LastIndexOf(";");
                    NewData.Add(strFileContent.Remove(nStartOf - 6));
                }
                else
                NewData.Add(strFileContent);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        foreach (string item in NewData)
        {
            if (item.Contains("^"))
            {
                if (pia != null)
                {
                    //if (pia.Suite == pia.City || pia.Suite == pia.PostalCode) pia.Suite = "";
                    sb.Append(pia.LastName + "," +
                        pia.FirstName + "," +
                        pia.StreetAddress + "," +
                        pia.Suite + "," +
                        pia.City + "," +
                        pia.PostalCode + "," +
                        pia.Telephone + "," +
                        pia.Fax);
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }

                pia.LastName = string.Empty;
                pia.FirstName = string.Empty;
                pia.StreetAddress = string.Empty;
                pia.Suite = string.Empty;
                pia.City = string.Empty;
                pia.PostalCode = string.Empty;
                pia.Telephone = string.Empty;
                pia.Fax = string.Empty;

                string[] strReplaceName = item.Split(',');
                pia.LastName = strReplaceName[0].Replace("^", "").Trim().ToString();
                pia.FirstName = strReplaceName[1].Trim().ToString();
            }

            #region Name, Address

            //if (item.Contains("^")) pia.FirstName = item;
            if (Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^\d"))
            {
                pia.StreetAddress = item.Replace(",", "");

                // Seperate Address if it contains Unit or Suite
                #region Seperate Address Line

                Match matchUnit = Regex.Match(item, @"[Unit]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (item.Contains("Unit") || item.Contains("Suite"))
                {
                    if (item.Contains("Unit"))
                    {
                        int nStart = item.IndexOf("Unit") + "Unit".Length;
                        pia.Suite = item.Substring(nStart);

                        if (Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^\d"))
                        {
                            //int a = item.Replace(item.Substring(nStart), string.Empty).Trim().Length;

                            string a = item;
                            int b = nStart;
                            if (a.Length - b == 0) pia.StreetAddress = item;
                            else
                                pia.StreetAddress = item.Replace(item.Substring(nStart), "").Trim();
                            //if(item.Replace(item.Substring(nStart), string.Empty).Trim() == "0") pia.StreetAddress = item;

                        }
                    }

                    if (item.Contains("Suite"))
                    {
                        int nStart = item.IndexOf("Suite") + "Suite".Length;
                        pia.Suite = item.Substring(nStart);

                        if (Regex.IsMatch(item, @"^\d")) pia.StreetAddress = item.Replace(item.Substring(nStart), "").Replace("Suite", "").Trim();
                    }
                }

                #endregion

            }

            #endregion

            #region City and Postal Code

            // Get the postal code
            Match matchPostalCode = Regex.Match(item, @"[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}[ -] *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (matchPostalCode.Success)
            {
                pia.PostalCode = matchPostalCode.ToString();

                // Get City
                if (item.Contains(matchPostalCode.ToString()) && item.Contains("ON"))
                {
                    string a = ", ON";
                    string b = "ON";
                    string c = " ON";
                    if (item.Contains(a)) pia.City = item.Replace(pia.PostalCode, "").Replace(a, "").Trim();
                    if (item.Contains(b)) pia.City = item.Replace(pia.PostalCode, "").Replace(b, "").Trim();
                    if (item.Contains(c)) pia.City = item.Replace(pia.PostalCode, "").Replace(c, "").Trim();
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Phone, Suite Number, Fax

            if (item.Contains("Phone")) pia.Telephone = item.Remove(0, 7);
            if (item.Contains("Suite") || item.Contains("Unit")) pia.Suite = item.Replace("Suite", "").Replace("Unit", "").Trim();

            if (item.Contains("Fax")) pia.Fax = item;

            #endregion

        }
        string g = sb.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Meh.csv", g);
    }
```

[image: When its to CSV]

Comment: tl;dr but it seems hard not to get the Phone and Fax in the right columns - they are labeled.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I added the headings afterwards, so when I posted this question that it could be seen what it looks like

Comment: That's even more confusing.

Comment: Its a visual representation so when I say that the address takes over the city as in Baskets record, you can see. I tried eleviating any confusion

Comment: I meant the "Phone:" in the text file. How did you end up getting that data in the wrong column?

Comment: The phone number ended up in the wrong column because I was having issues on certain records when extracting data from the strings. I had to rewrite a bit of it and now data is where its supposed to go.